# What is the largest value one can get in game 2048 without new tiles appear

Tags: algorithm

This is a simplified version of the famous game 2048. Given a 4x4 grids with some values chosen from `{0, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048}`. A value of `0` indicates that the position in the grid is unoccupied. What is the largest tile that can be produced by any (possible length-zero) sequence of moves (up, down, left,right) from the given game setup, if no new tiles were to be introduced to the grid?

For example, given

```
2 64 4 32
8 16 8 4
4 32 4 0
2 2 0 0
```

the answer is 128:

[image]

The problem can probably be solved by those AI algorithms (minmax for example), however, I guess that will definitely be an overkill. Is there any simpler algorithm to solve this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is a sequence of moves in this case? Largest tile?

Comment: @JaviV just the same rule as ordinary 2048 game playing, but no new tiles will be introduced. I meant the largest value can be obtained from the given 'partial' grids.

Comment: I totally recommend you to detail a bit more your question. With that information is almost impossible to know what you want. Disclaimer: the downvote is not mine, I'm more patient that others.

Comment: Did my answer solve your question or you are looking for something more?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest algorithm you can do in this case is a graph-based search. Every node of the graph represents a current state i of the grid. Every node has 4 children, representing state i+1 and therefore each edge represents a move (up, down, left, right).

So assume you start from the given state, node 1. Then you have to apply the 4 moves and simulate them. That is, node 1 has 4 children, node 2(with left movement), node 3(with right movement) and so on. For each movement you have simulate what that movement does. Store in each node the current state and the value of the maximum tile.

The algorithm would finish whenever there are no more possible movements. So looking for the maximum value of all the leaf nodes would do it.

The pseudo-code would be something like:

```
input: current state s_current
 output: max tile value M
 -----
 queue <- s_current
 while !queue.empty do
     s = queue.pop
     for each m in move // move contains the 4 moves.
         s' = simulate(s,m)
         if s' != 0 //so the move was possible
              queue.add(s')
         else
              mark s' as leaf node 
              M = max_tile(s')
              if M > M_current update M
```

DISCLAIMER: I have not checked for errors in the pseucode, probably some minor steps are missing.

Note that depending on queue datastructure, you are actually implementing a Breath First Search or Depth First Searh, which are the simplest graph algorithms you can implement. Actually, the most difficult part I see here is the `simulate()` function, which is the one that actually implements the logic of your game. I guess there are much better algorithms, but this is the most simple thing (and actually is not that bad :) )